WPF subscribe to WM_QUERYENDSESSION before Window is created
I have a WPF app where the Window is not visible through the whole execution of the program - in fact it might not even be instantiated. I'd like to receive and do something on messages WM_QUERYENDSESSION but can't really seem to find out how to do it.
I've tried creating a new WPF project with App.xml.cs as follows:
public partial class App : Application
{
    private const int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x0011;
    private HwndSource _hwndSource;
    
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File("D:\\Something\\Test.log").CreateLogger();
        Log.Information("Starting");

        CreateHiddenWindow();
    }

    private void CreateHiddenWindow()
    {
        Window hiddenWindow = new Window
        {
            Width = 0,
            Height = 0,
            ShowInTaskbar = false,
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
            AllowsTransparency = true,
            Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent
        };

        hiddenWindow.SourceInitialized += (s, e) =>
        {
            _hwndSource = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(hiddenWindow);
            _hwndSource.AddHook(WndProc);
            hiddenWindow.Hide();
        };

        hiddenWindow.Show();
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        Log.Information($"WndProc received message: {msg}");
        if (msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
        {
            Log.Information("WM_QUERYENDSESSION received in WndProc");
            Log.Information("Handled WM_QUERYENDSESSION, flushing logs...");
            Log.CloseAndFlush();

            handled = true;
        }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}

And this works... but requires a hidden window to be launched first. I also tried:
public partial class App : Application
{
    private const int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x0011;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File("D:\\Something\\Test.log").CreateLogger();
        Log.Information("Starting");

        ComponentDispatcher.ThreadFilterMessage += OnThreadFilterMessage;
    }

    private void OnThreadFilterMessage(ref MSG msg, ref bool handled)
    {
        Log.Information(msg.message.ToString());
        if (msg.message == WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
        {
            Log.Information("WM_QUERYENDSESSION received in OnThreadFilterMessage");
            Log.Information("Handled WM_QUERYENDSESSION, flushing logs...");

            Log.CloseAndFlush();

            handled = true;
        }
    }
}

But the second method doesn't work. How can I get this to work without a Window instance?
EDIT
By "doesn't work" I mean I receive a lot of messages but no WM_QUERYENDSESSION messages.

Well, AFAIK, you can't receive window messages without having a window. What's so bad about having a hidden one?

Maybe dumb question by why are you using a WPF Application object, etc., at all if there's no window? You can still use a lot of WPF APIs from a console or even server app,.

There is a window, just not all the time. Some things can be run silently without having to spawn any windows.
